# Save tkinter canvas for reimport and add-ons

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Strangely worded but a rather potential strange situation.

I'm plotting on a canvas a massive number of lines, err points in some cases.  This plotting goes beyond the edge of the screen...by the time all the data is included at a decent, usable resolution it would probably be in the area of 10,000-20,000x10,000-20,000 pixels...maybe bigger than that even.  In the current situation where I'm only displaying maybe 1-2% of the data to the screen it takes 30 seconds to create the graph.  I got to thinking this morning that maybe my best bet given how much more data is going to be presented before everything is said and done would be to create an initial graph and save the image and then display the image since it should be much quicker to display the image of the graph already created/saved then to create it each and every time I run the program.

I started doing some research into the idea this morning and have run into a few problems and questions to help me decide if this is a good idea or not.

When I try to

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

I get the error message that it cannot import ImageTk

If I try

```
import PIL
```

I get no errors.  I'm using Linux and Python 3.4.3.  Since several of the ideas involve ImageTk, how do I correct the importing problem?

Edit:
Also when I try

from PIL import ImageGrab

I get the error no module named _grabscreen.  Since that falls under PIL shouldn't it have been installed with PIL?

I know I would still need to install pyscreenshot to try the one technique I've seen presented here on SO.

Do any of these methods save the full canvas or only what you see on the physical screen. I would be wanting to save everything which is a much larger image then the physical screen display?

After saving the image and bringing it back up would I still be able to scroll around the image with tkinter?  As well, would I be able to add extras to the image, in terms of adding points of interest to the image(this would be a road map image).

So far I've only ever used tkinter for line graphs and not anything else so I don't have the experience to know the limitations versus what I might be wanting to do.

I have a few other ideas of how I might be able to handle the problem but none of the other ideas are as fast as this idea would be.

I just to need to get an idea as to what the limitations are to decide if I want to try to go any further with testing this idea out or not.

Thanks.

Comment: ImageTk is a separate install on Linux. For Debian-based systems: `sudo apt-get install python3-pil.imagetk`. However, you may not need it. If all you need is `PhotoImage` it's built into tkinter as `tkinter.PhotoImage`.

Comment: But to save the canvas what do I need?  Preferably, I think?????, not as postscript.  I haven't worked with postscript to know what I can get away with from postscript.  Can I bring the 'image' back up in tkinter once its saved.  I'm really ignorant here.

Comment: I'll add in I'm thinking probably in terms of gif or png since its only going to be line image, probable black background with white, red, blue, green or some color choice like that lines on the screen, again a road map.

Comment: Beats me. I only knew the answer to one of your questions.

Comment: No problem.  For other folks I figure I better add things in as I think of them.